# Why won't CL code compile with npm v 12.22

Tags: chainlink

When running make install on ubuntu server 20.04 the following error occurs:

error @: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^16.0.0". Got "12.22.2"

and it exits.

node --version returns v12.22.2

yarn --version returns 1.22.17

go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64

This is new, I have some ansible spinning up cl nodes regularly and this worked when v 1.10 dropped a couple weeks back - not sure if something in my environment is causing it to fail or if something in code was revised in last few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainlink was recently updated to require nodejs 16LTS

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/pull/5909

You should be able to update node via the following steps.

```
sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
node -v
```